# A Mule 4 policy template artifact cannot export packages

Tags: custom, mulesoft

I'm using Mule 4 to write a custom policy that includes a scripting component with Groovy that uses a Java class inside the script: `com.auth0`.
The project POM file has the Java as a dependency and sharedLibrary, Maven deploys with BUILD SUCCESS and sends it to Anypoint Platform, but when I activate the policy in API Manager I get an error logfile in the Mule Runtime server:

> *java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A policy template artifact cannot export packages*

I removed the sharedLibrary section from the POM file, redeployed and activated the policy, I get no error message but the scripting part does not work. Does that mean the custom policy is not able to run with Java? Should the Java class be installed in a different manner with maven?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying the same thing.  According to the documentation at:

https://docs.mulesoft.com/api-manager/2.x/custom-policy-4-reference

It states:

"Policies cannot export resources nor packages such as Java classes."

According to support if you want to run Java from a custom policy you must put it inside its own component according to KB article.

https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Calling-java-code-in-custom-policies-Mule-4-x?name=Calling-java-code-in-custom-policies-Mule-4-x&fromCase=1